# Most memory efficient way for searching within a string in C

Tags: c, performance, algorithm

What is the most memory efficient way to search within a string in ANSI C? (put the code up)

An example where this is needed is in embedded devices that are very short on available memory but nowadays have reasonable clock cycles.

Comment: searching for what within a string? another string? a char?

Comment: Asking for code? That's kinda moochy.

Comment: @Vlion: Asking for code on a programming Q&A site is moochy?

Comment: Yes.  You should ask for ideas, and write them into code yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure that the '(put the code up)' comment was the politest way to ask for the code, but I don't see that asking for code is necessarily bad.  Maybe '...in ANSI C (with code if that will make it clearer)?' would be better?

Comment: @ephemient: seconded.  We're not here to do the grunt work for you; we're here to help you understand how to do it for yourself.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you're looking for...but strchr() or strstr() are often appropriate.  And those are extremely memory efficient since they use no extra memory.

Answer (score 5):

Advancing one character at a time is Θ((n-m+1) m). Check into the [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm) algorithms for more efficient ways of searching for substrings -- both as low as O(n). Your handy algorithms textbook should discuss both of them. The standard C library strstr function implements one or both, so use that instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Good pointers, but I'm looking for _memory_ efficiency, not complexity-related efficiency... That is only a secondary concern for me. If the processor has a small cache (say 2kB) you may not want to do _any_ memory operations and just use the registers the CPU provides.

Comment: @Barry: are you sure strstr() ever implements BM or KMP searching?  Those typically require a pre-computation to speed up the search, and it is seldom reasonable to do that directly - the brute force works better for many situations.

Comment: You're right; things may have changed since the last time my algorithms class. The strstr.c in glibc doesn't use BM or KMP, nor does it do the naive algorithm.

Comment: What strstr() does depends on your compiler - Digital Mars uses BM, VC9 has a straight-forward set of nested while loops.

Comment: @ Mike B: interesting feedback - thanks.  I ran into a bug in an ancient version of strstr() on SunOS (pre-Solaris - that ancient!); it computed strlen() on the search string each iteration, which was critical since I was searching 64 KB blocks of text.  Sun fixed it (maybe not because of me).

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it depends on what you're searching for, but a linear search/comparison uses no more memory than the two strings (the 'host', and the 'token'). For example:

```
char host[] = "this is my string to search";
char token[] = "y st";
int k = 0;
while(host[k] != '\0'){
  for(int t=0; (token[t]!='\0' && host[k+t]!='\0');){
    if(host[k] == token[t]){
      t++;  // we matched the first char of token, so advance
    }
    else{   // no match yet, reset the token counter and move along the host string
      k++;
      t = 0;
    }
  }
  k++;
}
```

(I may be slightly off in the implementation, but hopefully you get my idea.)

Library functions like strstr should be worth looking at, too.

Comment: I knew someone'd have a shorter version than what I was coming-up with off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a substring, then strstr is very memory efficient. and for a char, strchr is also very memory efficient. Neither need extra storage.

I'm not sure if there is anything more that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the kind of search and the boundary conditions there is a large number of different algorithms for searching a sub-string in a string. A **large collection** is available here: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Karp Rabin just uses four ints and has linear average time. It just computes a hash of the search string and uses some math tricks to quickly get the hash of the next substring, given the hash of the substring before it.

The standard version runs into trouble because most languages don't do a true mathematical modulo but Gonnet and Baeza-Yate's *Handbook of Data Structures and Algorithms* has a [version](http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~rbaeza/handbook/algs/7/715.srch.c.html) which uses the word size as an implicit modulo (its also faster).

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem and just want to share my thoughts.

"Memory efficient" as I interpreted it is the ability to search a long string of size M given only N amount of available memory, M > N. This is alternative to an efficient use of memory per character available in the string to search. And I feel may be more relevant to the original poster's embedded environment (that may have a large storage).

Regardless of which algorithm you use to do the comparison (the more efficient the better of course), I would choose to use a circular buffer (which should be greater than the string you're search for, at least 2X perhaps?) and continuously load the stream of characters to the buffer while the search algorithm advances.  The search algorithm must be able to know how to wrap around the circular buffer (or add a level of indirection to hide the circular buffer from the search algorithm).